# returning login status in php [CURL]

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, authentication

how are you?
i have a non expected result ,
it should return "1" when login successfuly , and "0" when login error,

### and it always return "0"

```
<?php
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';
$loginUrl = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'log='.$username.'&pwd='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents('3.php', $content);

// if "Password" appear then login error;
echo preg_match("/Password/",file_get_contents("3.php"));

?>
```

and Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the output to a file is not necessary for this and will waste I/O. The second request to the index of the admincp can also saved for checking the login only because wordpress will print the loginform again when the login failed. So I modified your example like the following:

```
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';
$loginUrl = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'log=' . $username . '&pwd=' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(strpos($store, 'loginform') !== false) {
    echo 'Login not correct';
}else {
    echo 'Login ok';
}
```

But for me this seems not to be a good way of doing this. Depending on where you want to integrate this checks it will be a better solution to write a small plugin for the check or maybe integratin wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website Then you can use the wordpress-functions to check the credentials like https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password